# How can I pull out only the text which is between certain tags from an nvarchar db field containing HTML data

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I am not using XML as the datatype for storing HTML, rather simply storing it
as a string in an nvarchar database field.

In this html data\string I have tags `<description></description>` and
I want to fetch the text only between the said tags.

Also I presume I can't store normal html in an XML datatype field because
it would not be valid XML?

Comment: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: See also, as a warning: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
           XElement xmlTree = XElement.Parse("here put your html as string");
           var elements = xmlTree.Elements("description")
           foreach (XElement el in elements)
               Console.WriteLine(el);
```